# I created a UIAlertController using UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet and then added some buttons, but prompted me to have a layout problem

Tags: ios, objective-c

I created a UIAlertController using UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet and then added some buttons, but prompted me to have a layout problem. I am sure my code is fine, but I don't know where the problem is, please let me know if you know the reason.
And I tested the style as UIAlertControllerStyleAlert and didn't have this problem.

My project only supports iphone and does not support iPad. My development environment: Xcode: 10.2.1, iOS: 12.3.1

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"title" message:@"message" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

    UIAlertAction *cancleAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"cancle" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
        //NSLog(@"");
    }];

    UIAlertAction *sureAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"sure" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
        //NSLog(@"");
    }];

    [alertController addAction:cancleAction];
    [alertController addAction:sureAction];
    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:true completion:nil];
```

Debug output area printing:

```
[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282e9c5a0 UIView:0x1019286f0.width == -16>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282e9c5a0 UIView:0x1019286f0.width == -16>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Comment: Code look good, Refer this tutorials https://medium.com/@karthikkeyan/debugging-uiviewalertforunsatisfiableconstraints-47697696c7c . this will help you to identify the exact problem.

Comment: It's an iOS bug. Report it to Apple.

Comment: @rmaddy I also think so. then I want to know if there is any way to solve this problem.

Comment: @SGDev  yes, i am sure code good , I started testing with this code, no matter how I go to test it will prompt layout problems.

Comment: There is no way to solve it. It's not going to cause your app any issues.